# Правильно ли расставлены запятые? И если нет, то почему?

Tags: запятые, грамматика

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запятыми в предложении *"Лишь гладкие,  отстающие на километры, стены".*

Правильно ли расставлено? И если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Причастный оборот до определяемого слова не обособляется, а после - обособляется.

> Шуршащие на ветру листья колыхались.

> Листья, шуршащие на ветру, колыхались.

2. В случае двух определений выраженных прилагательным и причастным оборотом пунктуация следующая:

Зеленые, шуршащие на ветру листья колыхались.

Шуршащие на ветру зеленые листья колыхались.

Почему? я еще подумаю и напишу попозже)

А в вашем предложении запятые вроде так должны стоять:

"Лишь гладкие, отстающие на километры стены".

Для первой части: ["Оборот перед определяемым существительным"](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC/) - хотя тут лучше мозг не ломать и не выдумывать велосипед, а пойти по пути причастный оборот до определяемого слова. Я не знаю, как сделать из "отстающие на километры" обстоятельство, если кто знает - пишите в комментариях.

Для второй части: ["Запятая при однородном и неоднородном определении"](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC/)

Comment: Голос от меня. А так можно: Лишь гладкие, отстающие на километры, стены. Пожалуйста, подумайте и об  этом варианте тоже, а то мне интересно))

Comment: @Sharon я подумаю, но мне кажется, что все можно, но лучше не нужно), тогда получится что причастный оборот это не условие стен, то есть стены не являются определяемым, для этого причастного оборота, словом.

Comment: Писатели-классики иногда выделяли запятыми в качестве уточняющего определения причастный оборот, стоящий поcле однородного определения-прилагательного. Например, у И. С. Тургенева: Он устроил большую, полотном покрытую, купальню; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118  А я за писателей-классиков, но мне надо обосновать их решение.  Вот мне и интересно вше мнение. Здесь речь идет о выборе определительных или уточняющих значений.   Чем плох уточняющий причастный оборот?

Comment: @Sharon это не причастный оборот, это обстоятельство, полотном , покрытую относится к полоном, а не к купальню. То есть тут можно было: лишь гладкие, километрами отстающие, стены. Лишь гладкие, километровые, стены. Лишь гладкие стены, километровые. Но с таким же успехом можно и вообще не выделять запятыми: лишь гладкие километрами отстающие стены. С акцентом на километрами. И вообще тут главное слово будет километрами, которое хоть и обстоятельство, номинально, но по значимости важнее подлежащего.

Comment: @Sharon может, ничего не могу про это сказать. Я ориентируюсь на отношения слов друг к другу, связки. Смотря к чему относится связка, что есть определяемое слово, что есть определение. Как работает различие видов причастий?

Comment: Покрытые, отстающие - это причастия разного вида. Формально они относятся к существительному "купальня". Более тонкий смысл не выразишь ни в грамматике, ни на письме.

Comment: @Sharon не соглашусь, покрытую - причастие, причастие это некоторое условие. Покрытая полотном - можно образовать прилагательное, полотняная купальня, существительное "съест" причастие. А покрытая купальня - сразу возникает вопрос покрытая чем? Или покрытая - это вообще не признак, а уже термин, условие. Но тогда купальня - это не купальня русское слово, а купальня номинатив. Совсем другая логика. Проблема в том, что в русском языке существует сразу несколько логик восприятия фраз и слов

Comment: Спасибо, я подумаю.  В то же время  примеров с такой моделью предложения много. поэтому интересен общий поход к ним  тоже.

Comment: @Sharon По-русски чёрный кот, это цвет вот этого кота, а по-английски, чёрный кот - это название или классификация выделяющая и характеризующая объект, черного (цвета) кошачье (животное), как то так это звучит. По-русски, кот чёрный - этот, мой, чёрный кот, кот чёрный - не важно. А по-английский будет разница: моё кошачье черное цвета, черный цвет у моего кошачьего... Причём по-русски еще кот - это не кошка, то есть уже какие-то личные или индивидуальные особенности включены.

Comment: @Sharon Так же могут быть смещены акценты как чёрные коты - тогда уже речь идет не о каком-то коте, однако, все равно это не кошачьи. Можно сказать чернота кота - согласовать наоборот.
 В английском это сделать сложнее, да и не нужно, потому что там нет кота, а есть классы - кошачьи. Поэтому, смотря что здесь хочет сказать автор, он хочет подчеркнуть особенность своей купальни? возможно, и делает это вот такой таким синтаксисом. Но правила - это скорее для общих моментов, нечто среднее.

Comment: @Sharon То есть в русском можно семантики добавить как с помощью согласования, так и с помощью синтаксиса - который интонация при произнесении, прочтении. То есть речевые моменты влияют на значение фразы, а не только расположением слов-терминов/-понятий. Форма определяется речью, а не наоборот. А русские слова часто не понятия, а именования вещей, не номинативы.

Comment: @Sharon ну и это все мои мысли - то что я только, что придумал. Хотя с точки зрения причины мне кажется разница в этом примета накая. Слова в русском - не номинативы, не термины, и не понятий, но могут принимать те или иные роли в зависимости от того, что хочет сказать говорящий. В английском это сделать сложнее, так как там уже заложено деление, однако, иногда начинают писать слова с большой буквы, чтобы вывести их значения из категорий понятий, терминологии и прочего. То есть английский, как бы определенный, с возможностью неопределенности, а русский наоборот.

Comment: @Sharon но из русского можно сделать кривоватую версию английского, а вот из английского русский вряд ли получится сделать.

Comment: @Sharon возможно синтаксис отражает ту логическую модель, которая применима к прочитываемому тексту. То есть синтаксис, это как бы надстройка над словесно-языковой базой(семантической базой), синтаксис отсутствует в китайском, синтаксис редко встречается в английском, мне кажется, что в русском синтаксис один из самых сложных, хотя я точно не знаю, нужно проверить эту догадку.

Comment: Буратино, при ответах принято давать ссылку на соответствующие правила.

Comment: @Серж добавил) спасибо Шампару.