# "Подобно голодному хищнику". Нужна запятая?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая в такой конструкции:

Подобно голодному хищнику (?) он чуял предстоящий скандал?

По Розенталю выходит, что нужна. Или нет?

Comment: А можно ссылку на Розенталя? Мне кажется, тут "подобно голодному хищнику" относится не к ОН, а к ЧУЯЛ. То есть запятая нужна была бы, если бы было ОН = ГОЛОДНЫЙ ХИЩНИК. Подобно голодному хищнику, он вцепился зубами в плоть - он = хищник. А тут даже не подобно хищнику, а подобно голодному чуял, чуял подобно голодному, хищнику дополнение, и нет конфликта, просто набор определений причем до определяемого (глагола?)

Comment: Проблема в моём рассуждении, что определения относятся к существительным, а не к глаголам. Короче мне даже пришлось заглянуть в правила тут недавно, выглядело это так: https://orfogrammka.ru/пунктуация/оборот_перед_определяемым_существительным/
Выделяется в случае "обстоятельства", является ли подобно голодному хищнику обстоятельством? Ну если можно было бы заменить являясь хищником - то, наверное, это было бы обстоятельством, но тут подобно хищнику, или даже подобно голодному - то есть не обстоятельство и не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо! Я совсем не там смотрела. В правиле о сравнительных оборотах искала ответ. Но ваша версия, думаю, ближе к истине )). Можно, я не буду давать ссылку? Вижу, что ошиблась ).

Comment: Да ваше право, что давать) можете вообще не отвечать) у меня самого есть одна ссылка, вот её и даю) да и та не моя, я её вчера позаимствовал у Шампара. И использовал её для одного примера, там правда был более очевидный пример, чем тут. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474655/Правильно-ли-расставлены-запятые-И-если-нет-то-почему/474656#474656 Там ребята стали говорить, что мол причастный оборот может и обособляться и тд, я сказал, это мол не причастный оборот, поэтому там обособляется, это обстоятельство, потом нашел ссылку на эти правила, которые подтвердили мою догадку.

Comment: @Татьяна  В конце заданного для рассмотрения предложения (в ваших вопросах) нежелательно ставить вопросительный знак, а то неясно, к чему он относится. Здесь еще контекст не помешал бы.  А это общее правило http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_538&layout=item

Comment: В вашем вопросе уже есть ответ. Раз это именно уподобление, то, без сомнения, запятая нужна. Подобно голодному хищнику = словно голодный гищник, ...

Comment: @Ajgy а что если: он чуял - это нюхал воздух, он чуял как голодный хищник? Тут еще диссонанс, как хищник может чувствовать скандал? Он может его провоцировать, а чуять может жертва. То есть тут диссонанс с семантикой, если он = голодный хищник. Типа он специально пришел в место, где кто-то устроил скандал, чтобы поживиться чем-то?

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо, учту ваше замечание по поводу знака вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

***Подобно голодному хИщнику**, // **он чуял предстоящий скандАл.***

1. Это тема обособления обстоятельственных оборотов с **производными** предлогами
   [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) и  [Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_538&layout=item)
2. Решение **факультативное**, выбор делается по семантике и структуре предложения, а также с учетом контекста и стиля речи.
3. Обособление **более вероятно**: художественный стиль, начало предложения, равновесная структура, близкая к структуре СПП с придаточным сравнительным.
4. Необособленный вариант возможен при логическом **подчеркивании** оборота: ***Подобно голодному хИщнику** / он чуял предстоящий скандал.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147510/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, у меня появилась идея:

Ввиду того, что, если считать он-хищник, который чует скандалы, тут чует будет выступать в переносном значении, то есть ищет, скандалы, чтобы поживится. Есть тонкий момент: чуять может жертва хищника, а хищник чуя жертву не чует, а действует, организует скандал, травлю. То есть хищник актор скандала, а не субъект, по отношению к нему глагол имеет прямое значение, а по отношении к жертве глагол будет иметь косвенное значение и будет предикацией будет иметь косвенное значение.

Я бегу домой - предикат домой, а не бегу.

Уже бегу - предикат уже.

Я уже бегу домой - предикат уже.

То есть сам глагол, не будет в обычной ситуации не будет предикатом.

А вот если:

- Ты идешь, где ты там? - Я не иду, я бегу! - тут даже не добавишь "домой" потому что акцент на слове бегу. Либо просто: Бегу, бегу! То есть уже-уже/скоро - предикат.

Но тут есть момент - указание бежать, или тот - кто его торопит. То есть Я становится не актором, автором действия, а действующим субъектом - выполняющим указание.

Вот тут начинается игра значений и семантика.

Если вы еще посмотрите выше, то ответ быть "я не иду", потому что субъект оценил слово "идешь" и занес его в категории не глаголов действия, глаголов образов действия, то есть подверг его семантизации, подобрал ассоциацию более точную. Если бы от ответил "иду", диалог мог бы выглядить так:

- Где ты там потерялся, ты идешь, где ты там? - Я иду! - Быстрей иди!

Второму, тому кто устраивает конфликт, пришлось бы внести предикацию, иначе фраза "я иду" выглядит слишком расслабленной и аморфной.

К чему это все я?

К тому, что глаголы действия предикатами в их истинном проявлении не являются, это просто описание факта. А вот если это слово-перевертыш, то есть не имеющее прямого значения, а только косвенное, условное, то тогда начинаются выкрутасы и нужны запятые.

Comment: Буратино, это очень интересная версия. Мне нужно несколько раз прочесть, чтобы переварить ))) Спасибо, что не оставляете мои вопросы без ответа!